# Forge DA Inventor model parametrization speed insufficient on forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have a speed issue with parametrization of an inventor model. It is an assembly with env. 20 parameters, a few parts with no dependencies. Parametrization is done by transforming the parts at their location in space using iLogic and a helper dll. The complexity is reduced to env. 30% of the estimated, final model.

Running the workitem with the parametrization activity of this model takes env. 1 min 40 sec. Which is definitively too much. Creating the same parameter changes in a local Inventor takes env. 10 sec.

Are there any ideas where to start to speed up this task?

Comment: In order to know more where the time is spent I would need to see report file from processing of the Workitem. Would it be possible to share it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichalVasicek Thanks for the tip. Helped me figure out where we wasted time. Seems that iLogic is consuming much more than expected.

Comment: In case you found something strange in your iLogic, I would recommend you to turn on iLogic detailed logging on FDA using "iLogicVb.Automation.LogControl.Level = LogLevel.Trace
". See https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/inventor_specific/ilogic-logging/